# Method regexp_replace([class org.apache.spark.sql.Column, class java.lang.String, class java.lang.Integer]) does not exist in Pyspark

Tags: machine-learning, pyspark

I am working on a machine learning model using Pyspark. during categorical values handling using regexp_replace I got this error... is it a version problem??

[image]

Answer (score 1):

According to the [`regexp_replace`'s docs](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.0.1/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.regexp_replace), the last parameter should be a string as well, but you're passing an integer.